# How to get List<Y> from Map<X,Y> by providing List<X> using google collection?

Tags: java, guava

I have a `Map<X, Y>` and `List<X>`, I would like to extract the values from `Map<X, Y>` by providing  the `List<X>`, which will result in `List<Y>`. One way to do this is

```
List<X> keys = getKeys();  
Map<X, Y> map = getMap();  
List<Y> values = Lists.newArrayListWithCapacity(keys.size());  
for(X x : keys){  
   values.add(map.get(x));  
}
```

Now again I need to remove nulls in values (`List<Y>`) by using Predicate or something. Any better way to do this?
Is there any good reason why this method isn't there in google collections library?

Comment: even if you add the null check in the code above, it would be much more readable than the answers below. but, thats just my opinion ;) https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/FunctionalExplained

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this:

```
List<Y> values = Lists.newArrayList(
    Iterables.filter(
        Lists.transform(getKeys(), Functions.forMap(getMap(), null), 
        Predicates.notNull()));
```

Answer (score 0):

[@axtavt's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033209/how-to-get-listy-from-mapx-y-by-providing-listx-using-google-collection/5033276#5033276) would probably be the most efficient given your exact requirements. If your `List` of keys were instead a `Set`, something like this would be my preference:

```
List<Y> values = Lists.newArrayList(
    Maps.filterKeys(getMap(), Predicates.in(getKeys())).values());
```

I think a special method for doing this isn't in Guava because it's not generally useful enough. Plus, as you can see there are ways of composing things Guava does provide to achieve this. Guava focuses on providing building blocks, with specific methods for operations that are very common.

Comment: Agreed.. but which way is more efficient 1) which I mentioned in question 2) Answer provided by @axtavt

Comment: @Premraj: I think @axtavt's solution is more efficient because it only has to iterate once through the keys list. The solution in the question would require iterating through the keys list and then again through the values list to remove null. That could be solved by using `Iterables.filter(keys, notNull())` when you iterate, but that's basically what @axtavt's solution already does.

Comment: While I like the functional approach better, Premraj could have done the null-check inside the for loop, if he wanted to go with his iterative solution: for (X x : keys) {Y y = map.get(x); if (y != null) { values.add(y); }}
This would avoid traversing the list twice.
The only difference performance-wise between both approaches, is that axtavt solution might need to resize its ArrayList multiple times, while Premraj sets the capacity at construction time. It's a trade-off, since he might also end up initializing a big array to hold a few entries...

Comment: @eneveu: You're right, he could just do a simple null check in the loop. @axtavt's solution could avoid the resizing by initializing the `ArrayList` first with the expected size and then using `Iterables.addAll` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Same concept as [axtavt's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5033276/305973), but using `FluentIterable` (reads sequentially instead of inside-out):

```
List<Y> values = FluentIterable
    .from(keys)
    .transform(Functions.forMap(map, null))
    .filter(Predicates.notNull())
    .toList();
```